# Is there an API for user badges?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, api

Is there was a way to pull down 'badges' for users of various sites in the network. I noticed that there is an [API call for all badges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges) in the system, but can't see one for users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if there was a way to pull down 'badges' for users of various sites in the network

If you have their user IDs, you can get a list of badges they have with the `/users/{ids}/badges` API method. For example, [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users#order=desc&sort=rank&ids=1624933&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) will return your Stack Overflow badges.

[image]